# About age restrictions on marriage in Hinduism

Tags: marriage, customs

1. Is there any restriction in Hinduism that female partner must be younger than the corresponding male partner for marriage? If it is there, why?
2. According to Hindu texts, is there any restriction on the maximum and minimum age gap between the marrying couple?

Comment: The restrictions are only on marrying in same blood, this has a scientific relation about some Genetic Disorders and it harms the Immune systems of the future generation as a result they opt atheism as they don't have the mental capability to understand the spiritual text or religions

Comment: Yes, there are restrictions on ages. You can get info on this by referring Shodasa Sanskara. And the age difference must be close to 5-10 years.

Comment: If i am not wrong the Sita is older then Ram. Then this restrictions of age are just man made.

Comment: They are man made for sure(those men were our ancient rishis), but it do have it's benefices, both social and scientific. Also how do you say that Sita is older than Sreeram?

Comment: The only restriction was that one shouldn't marry up to 7th cousins for genetic purposes. the concept of Gotra came about to simplify this further (although with India's current day's large population, Gotra is probably irrelevant).

Comment: @uday you said "The only restriction was that one shouldn't marry up to 7th cousins for genetic purposes" so it is up to the couple .  Religion will allow .isn't it ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Sita is not older than Rama. She is about 7 years younger than him according to the Valmiki Ramayana. She was 6 and he was 13 when they wed.

Comment: @moonstar2001 6 yer source? Sources says its not 6 for sure [1](http://jindgikipaathshala.blogspot.fr/2010/03/delusion-pertaining-to-marriage-and-age.html),[2](http://www.quora.com/Ramayana/What-was-the-age-of-Rama-and-Sita-when-they-got-married)

Comment: I read somewhere that she is older but not sourced, that’s why it was comment not answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma No worries, Ankit. I am just sharing what I know so that we get clarity about misconceptions that are fed to us. I too was told that she was older till I came across the actual story. The source is Valmiki Ramayan- Sita kalyana ghatta.

Comment: Yes, she must be younger by at least 1 year. Recommended is 3+ years. More than 20 is not recommended. Also, girl's age ideally close to 10 in olden days (but no physical relations until she attains maturity), and 16 nowadays, but 18 due to law. Still sooner the better. Older than 30, they might have physical birth-related issues. Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10018/what-is-the-recommended-age-for-marriage-for-girls-as-per-shastra

Answer (score 1):

1. Some people say that women have more maturity than men at a particular age. Hence to balance them a difference of 4-5 years is recommended. My mother had told me that men's life expectancy is less than woman and they start getting health problems earlier than women. So in order to match their these periods, it is done so, so that both can tackle all problems together.
2. There is no such rule for age gap. In medival times, adult men married child girls. (That's wrong of course). But the age gap must not be much, +ve or -ve

Comment: "that's wrong of course" - according to who? child marriage does not mean child 'physical relations'. child would only be sent to husband's home after she gets period. kama (desire) enters heart by 12. if girls are not married by then, there is high chance of them going astray (as we see today with girls going behind rowdy boys). the age gap must be much, according to manu smriti.

Comment: @Shreemay Panhalkar include references! I downvoted your post.