# What is the correct age of marriage for men?

Tags: marriage, sex, men

What is the correct age for marriage for a boy ?
Until advent of modernity (in about 1950s,) historically both boys and girls used to get married before puberty, in childhood.

In case of [women](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10018/what-is-the-recommended-age-for-marriage-for-girls-as-per-shastra) , [shastras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34832/what-to-do-when-scriptures-go-against-conscience) have some injuctions.

What is the case with boys ?

What is the correct age for marriage for boys ?

Comment: For dvija boys, Vivāha is to be performed after the Samāvartana. Samāvartana is a saṁskāra which marked the boy's return from gurukula & release from the vows of celibacy. This means that brāhmaṇas can't marry before their upanayana. Since they are devoid of Samāvartana, there is no minimum age of marriage for śūdras.

Comment: [Related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/47840/is-there-a-scripturally-recommended-age-of-marriage-for-men)